# How to check if a row exists in a table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using this code to check if a row exists in my table:

```
public boolean checkIdiomInFavorite(Idiom idiom){
        String query = "SELECT *" +  " from " + IdiomsOpenHelper.TABLE_FAVORITE +
                " where " + IdiomsOpenHelper.COLUMN_FAV_ID + " = ?;";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query,new String[] { String.valueOf(idiom.getId()) });
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            return true;
        }
        else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But always I get `false`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace this

```
if(cursor.moveToNext()){
        return true;
    }
    else{ 
        return false;
    }
```

with

```
return(cursor.moveToFirst());
```

Comment: Does the record exist in the specified table, with that condition matched?

Comment: Yes, I've tested in database, it returns the record.

Comment: What does `idiom.getId()` return?

Comment: So, does this query `String query = "SELECT * FROM " + IdiomsOpenHelper.TABLE_FAVORITE +
                " WHERE " + IdiomsOpenHelper.COLUMN_FAV_ID + " = 5";` work?

Comment: Yes it does, I test this query, it returns the record: `code`SELECT * FROM Favorite WHERE _id = 5`code`

Comment: And does the query `SELECT * FROM Favorite WHERE _id = 5` return a record?

Comment: Yes, it returns the record.

Comment: SO, here `database.rawQuery(query,new String[] { String.valueOf(idiom.getId()) });`, what if you remove the `String.valueOf` part? Just leaving `database.rawQuery(query,new String[] {idiom.getId()});`

Comment: `idioms.getId()` returns long, I should convert it to string

Comment: I also test it with inserted number in database: `database.rawQuery(query,new String[] { "5" });` still getting false.

Comment: So `cursor.getCount()` returns 0?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : Calling `return (cursor.getCount() > 0)` after a check for `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` is completely redundant. When a query returns a `Cursor`, its position is set to -1. Assuming the `Cursor` references at least 1 record then `moveToFirst()` by its very definition will indicate that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Change this query string...

```
String query = "SELECT *" +  " from " + IdiomsOpenHelper.TABLE_FAVORITE +
            " where " + IdiomsOpenHelper.COLUMN_FAV_ID + " = ?;";
```

...to...

```
String query = "SELECT * from " + IdiomsOpenHelper.TABLE_FAVORITE +
            " where " + IdiomsOpenHelper.COLUMN_FAV_ID = " + idiom.getId();
```

Then change this line...

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query,new String[] { String.valueOf(idiom.getId()) });
```

...to...

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
public boolean checkIdiomInFavorite(Idiom idiom){
        String query = "SELECT *" +  " from " + IdiomsOpenHelper.TABLE_FAVORITE +
                " where " + IdiomsOpenHelper.COLUMN_FAV_ID + " = ?;";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query,new String[] { String.valueOf(idiom.getId()) });
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            return true;
        }
        else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

can u able to detect the deference? I am using SELECT *, what means all the columns ... or use any column name you actually have in that table.

You also can count the total rows of the table to check if it returns 0... if returns 0 then no data exists.